# Make Google apps usermode

Tags: google-apps, system-apps

I want to have minimal google apps (market, gmail, sync) as user apps without any permission to the system. like prevent google to force-remove an app from my phone etc. I saw once google apps installer for MIUI roms that did it but it does not work anymore. also cant convert in Titanium. running on AOSP so no gapps by default. I would be really thankful for answer. so thank you in advance.

Comment: You could [use microG](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-5a) for basic GServices, some [alternative market app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets) (yes, there are some to access even Google Play), use a decent mail app like k9, and sync with your own resources (or those of other providers). Getting free of Google but sticking with Gmail & co is a bit half-hearted :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you're asking. Do you mean that you wish to **uninstall** several Google apps to only have  a few apps by Google on your phone?

Are you rooted? If you have root access, what you can do is use [ROM Toolbox Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro&hl=en) to remove system apps (Google apps) from your phone without needing to flash a different ROM for this ability.

Please let me know if this answers your question or if I misunderstood your question.

**Rooting a device:** This can be accomplished using several different methods. There are several one-click root apps like KingRoot, Framaroot or TowelRoot.

---

**Convert System Apps -> User Apps**

You can use an app called **[/system/app mover.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.systemappmover&hl=en)** This is an easier method.

Comment: yes I have root access. I am a dev, so you can freely tell me what to do :)

Comment: I mean to make google apps as user apps. as they are system apps by default.

Comment: they are like default messaging app. I want them to be like Facebook app. to have no access except for installed apps. it absolutely worked for me on MIUI (Android 5.0), but on current 7.1.1 it does not work.

Comment: so I need a manual way to do this.

Comment: sure any love with terminal, UNIX systems for ages) just kinda new to android. I guess just moving them to /data/app/ wont work as they have shared libs.

Comment: You can try this app (root required): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.systemappmover&hl=en

Comment: well, Titanium couldn't accomplish this, but sure I will try...

Comment: best way would be to install them as user apps directly.

Comment: The app is a rather simple solution without going through extra work, so maybe it will work. Best of luck. :-)

Comment: well, they are simply disappeared :)

Comment: so /system/app mover won't work. gonna restore n-ackup...

Comment: Strange as it worked for me -- but perhaps my ROM allows such action. Some ROMs will have a safeguard in place. I'm really not sure, then, sorry.

Comment: well, selinux permissive too. do you have 7.1.1 ? as it might be that Titanium and /system/app does not know how to work with apps in this case. As I've heard Google changed the way apps installs. anyway - thank you for respond :)

Comment: I actually have 6.0.1. Yes, actually now that you mention it; you're correct. Google changed the way apps are installed and it's more secure (and annoying for situations like yours). I hope you find a workaround. :)